# How to create HyperLink 'Click here' using Node.js

Tags: node.js, protractor

How to create HyperLink  'Click here' using Node.js
I have a link which i am sending in an email. Instead of this i want to send a 'Click here' as a hyperlink and when user click on it , it redirects to the main link.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess you are generating the content of your email with node.js
You need to send an email with an HTML content and in that content add the link `<a href="http://google.com">Click Here</a>`

To achieve this I suggest you using `nodemailer` https://nodemailer.com/ which is quite a standard to send emails in node.

the code would look something like this:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Fred Foo <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    html: '<b>Hello world <a href="http://google.com">clickHere</a></b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Comment: I was already using the nodemailer but were not aware of HTML part in mail options.
Thanks! a lot .